# why java ReentrantLock not throw InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I want to create race condition in Java thread Concurrency and create deadlock.
 I use ReentrantLock, but it doesn't throw InterruptedException.

It is deadlock now, and I use lockInterruptibly, but it doesn't throw InterruptedException, can any body tell me why?

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final Object o1 = new Object();
        final Object o2 = new Object();

        final ReentrantLock l1 = new ReentrantLock();
        final ReentrantLock l2 = new ReentrantLock();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    l1.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("I am in t1 step 1 " + o1.toString());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    l2.lock();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("I am in t1 step 2 " + o2.toString());
                    } finally {
                        l2.unlock();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    l2.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("I am in t2 step 1 " + o2.toString());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    l1.lock();
                    try {
                        System.out.println("I am in t2 step 2 " + o1.toString());
                    } finally {
                        l1.unlock();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t1.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

    }
}
```

Comment: I think `competition` should be `race condition`...

Answer (score 1):

The 2 threads are deadlocked in lines: `l1.lock()` and  `l2.lock()`. So when you interrupt them they don't react. If you replace all `lock()` calls with `lockInterruptibly()` you'll get the exception.

EDIT:
I prepared simpler example that will generate race condition as you want:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final ReentrantLock l1 = new ReentrantLock();
        final Random rn = new Random();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(1000)); //wait 0-999 ms
                    l1.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("Thread 1 won");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 1 interrupted");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(1000)); //wait 0-999 ms
                    l1.lockInterruptibly();
                    System.out.println("Thread 2 won");
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Thread 2 interrupted");
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t1.interrupt();
        t2.interrupt();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

    }
}
```

With this code you'll get randomly one of two outputs every time you run it:

```
Thread 1 won
Thread 2 interrupted
```

or

```
Thread 2 won
Thread 1 interrupted
```

depending on the generated random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each thread tries to take two locks.

```
                // Thread 1.
                l1.lockInterruptibly();
                // ....
                l2.lock();


                // Thread 2.
                l2.lockInterruptibly();
                // ....
                l1.lock();
```

So each thread grabs a lock and then tries to grab the lock the other thread already holds. This is called a deadlock.

You are not seeing the `java.lang.InterruptedException` because the lock the threads are waiting on (the second one) is not an interruptable lock.

Fix this with:

```
                // Thread 1.
                l1.lockInterruptibly();
                // ....
                l2.lockInterruptibly();


                // Thread 2.
                l2.lockInterruptibly();
                // ....
                l1.lockInterruptibly();
```

Comment: thank you :-), you are right, I have to use lockInterruptibly when use the second lock for every thread.

Answer (score 0):

Reentrant means that a single Thread that already holds a lock can retake it.

In your case there are two different Threads creating.

This is called **Reentrance lockout**, is a situation similar to deadlock and nested monitor lockout.

you can fix this by in Thread t1

```
            l1.lockInterruptibly();
            System.out.println("I am in t1 step 1 " + o1.toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            l2.lockInterruptibly();
```

and in Thread t2

```
            l2.lockInterruptibly();
            System.out.println("I am in t2 step 1 " + o2.toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            l1.lockInterruptibly();
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't throw InterruptedException, can any body tell me why?

Maybe because the purpose for which `ReentrantLock` was created is *mutual exclusion*.

Any time a thread in your program holds a mutex locked for more than a tiny fraction of a second, that's a bad code smell.

Making the `lock.lock()` call interruptible would complicate all of the programs that use it:  Every place you want to lock a lock, you'd have to write a handler for the `InterruptedException`.

My guess (and that's all it is) is that the authors thought they should not make all programmers have to write those extra interrupt handlers just so that *some* programmers could use `ReentrantLock` in bad designs.